# How to make ffmpeg insert timestamp in filename

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to make a bash script that grabs a still shot from an IP camera and than emails it.

Using

```
ffmpeg -i http://admin:Stupidpassword1@10.12.10.40/Streaming/channels/1/picture \
  -f image2 -updatefirst 1 doorbell.jpg
```

From what I have read this should work but the output file name is still `doorbell.jpg` How can I make the filename `TIMESTAMPdoorbell.jpg`?

Answer (score 16):

Use the "strftime" feature:

```
ffmpeg -i http://admin:Stupidpassword1@10.12.10.40/Streaming/channels/1/picture -vframes 1 -f image2 -strftime 1 "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S_doorbell.jpg"
```

"-vframes 1" will cause it to only process the first frame that it receives.

You can change the date/time format using a strftime compatible string:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html

Further documentation/examples:
https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-2

Comment: The strftime feature does not work unless also using a muxer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61874916/2394945