# ffmpeg strftime no effect on windows

Tags: ffmpeg, strftime

I'm trying to auto mark the output file with timestamps with ffmpeg. Here's my test cmd:

```
.\ffmpeg.exe -y -loglevel 99 -i test.mp3 -strftime 1 %Y.ogg
```

I expected a file named `2020.ogg`, however only got `%Y.ogg`. In another word, output filename is not processed by `strftime()`. I'm using powershell so there should be no relation with cmd's `%%` escaping.

Here's the output: https://pastebin.com/LUVh2kFA I'm using static builds from https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com (Thanks Zeranoe!) I confirmed that the problem exists in v4.2.2 and git-20200515. Is there any chance to fix it or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-strftime` is not a general option and is only supported by certain [muxers](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#toc-Muxers). A workaround is to use the [segment muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment_002c-stream_005fsegment_002c-ssegment) and to provide a `-segment_time` longer than the expected output duration:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -f segment -strftime 1 -segment_time 10:00:00 %Y.ogg
```

Comment: You saved my day! A little more to be mentioned, when using complex input source and with `segment_format` parameter, `segment` might not recognize the output file correctly, complaining ``. I fixed it by adding `-map 0` before `-f segment`.

Comment: It's a little pity that with `segment`, bitrate is always "N/A". I've read the manual but found nothing. Are there workarounds about it?

Comment: @Ben Use `ffprobe` after the file has been encoded: `ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=bit_rate -of csv=p=0 2020.ogg`

Comment: Actually I 'd prefer to monitor it (by reading ffmpeg's output with pipe). Seems no luck. Anyway thank you again!